# Integrating two variables for $L^1$ function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Is it necessarily true that $$\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x-y)g(y)|dxdy=\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|dx\int_\mathbb{R}|g(y)|dy.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. The result is immediate from Fubini's theorem and the translation-invariance of Lebesgue measure, for we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x - y) g(y)| dx dy &=\int_{\mathbb R} |g(y)| \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x - y)| dx dy \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} |g(y)| \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| dx dy \\
&= \|g\|_1 \|f\|_1
\end{align*}